# Why do we get error for checking string value in sql

Tags: sql, database, oracle, cursor

I'm running this piece of code implemented with cursor 
but I get if statement error after running it

```
declare
  cursor cr is
   select idd,name from tes;
     begin
       for n in cr
         IF n.name = '' THEN
          insert into tes2 values(n.idd,'$$$');
         ELSE
          insert into tes2 values(n.idd,n.name);
         END IF;
    end loop;
    commit;
   end;
```

the error :

> Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the following:
>
> . ( * @ % & - + / at loop mod remainder rem ..     || multiset

The type of my variable are varchar2 and I also tried if n.name is NULL , didn't work.

Comment: you forgot the "loop":  for n in cr LOOP ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `for` statement, you forgot to add `loop`. `End loop` is there but no starting of loop. Try after changing below portion

```
for n in cr 
   loop
         IF n.name = '' THEN 
          insert into tes2 values(n.idd,'$$$'); 
         ELSE 
          insert into tes2 values(n.idd,n.name); 
         END IF; 
    end loop;
```